# How to take the limit of of the real part of a complex value

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

Suppose that
$$
\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{-\sum_{k=1}^\infty k(k+1)b_k a_kz^k}{[\mu(1-\theta)+\theta]/z-\sum_{k=1}^\infty k[\mu(k+\theta)-\theta]b_k a_kz^k}\right)\geq \alpha\tag{$\ast$}
$$
where $0\leq \theta\leq 1,1/2\leq \mu\leq 1,0\leq \alpha\leq 1,a_k\geq 0,b_k\geq 0$.

My professor stated (without proof) that if we let $z\rightarrow 1^-$ through real values then $(*)$ implies that

$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty k[\mu(k+\theta)-\theta]b_k a_k \leq \mu(1-\theta)+\theta
$$

Can you please show me why this is true?

Comment: "$(\ast)$ is reduced to" or "$(\ast)$ implies"?

Comment: @Gary I think "implies" is more accurate translation. My course is not in English.

Comment: There's no shame in asking the professor for an explanation.

Comment: Hm, where did the $\alpha$ go?

Comment: @angryavian I think it implies that since the real value is bigger than alpha which is positive then the bottom must be positive. NOT sure if this is correct.

Comment: @gbd My problem is that at the same time the numerator is negative which would indicate an inequality in the reverse order.